# ASP.Net MVC 4 & Unobtrusive Validation Summary

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, unobtrusive-validation

I am trying to display a summary error message on a form as well as property level errors.

The property errors get rendered using `html.validationmessagefor(model =>...)`  which works fine.

But when there is one or more validation errors, I want `html.ValidationSummary(true)` to display the message "Your form is missing some details - see below".

There also might be some server side validation which will occur post submit and will be added with `ModelState.AddError`.

How can I get a class level dataattribute (presumably using `[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class)])` to display in the summary validation using unobtrusive validation?

Comment: Unless there is a better way to do this...

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
        @Html.ValidationSummary("Errors:")

        <div>
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.PathToExcel)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.PathToExcel)
        </div>

            <div>
            <input type="submit" value="Load" />
        </div>
}
```

this uses 2 ValidationSummary's, one to fill the ValidationMessageFor-fields and one to use a Summary. Summary only works after Submitting.